# JAVA SDK not found error in unity 2021 and tells to install from unityhub but on unity hub it shows it is installed

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, installation

I am using `Unity 2021.3.0f1` on `ubuntu 20.04` and getting error:

```
UnityException: JDK not found
Java Development Kit (JDK) directory is not set or invalid. Please, fix it in Edit / Unity -> Preferences -> External Tools
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /home/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

but when I try to install through `unityhub` it shows that jdk is installed (Check screen shot below) .

[image: unity]

so how can I reinstall it.

thank you in advance for helping me out

Comment: Did you check the settings are pointing to it?

Comment: @BugFinder I dont about checking settings as I am completely new to unity. but can you help me to solve the error above?

Answer (score 0):

I would give this [forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-build-fails-with-unityexception-jdk-not-found.781850/) a read. If you are new to Unity and haven't been to the Unity forums, that's usually a better place to get help for debugging Unity problems.